# What's the difference between master and refs/heads/master in jenkins job branch specifier

Tags: git, jenkins

They discourage using `<branch>` as branch specifier for job and recommend using `refs/heads/<branch>`:

> Specify the branches if you'd like to track a specific branch in a repository. If left blank, all branches will be examined for changes and built.
>
> The safest way is to use the `refs/heads/<branchName>` syntax. This way the expected branch is unambiguous.
>
> If your branch name has a `/` in it make sure to use the full reference above. When not presented with a full path the plugin will only use the part of the string right of the last slash. Meaning `foo/bar` will actually match bar.
>
> If you use a wildcard branch specifier, with a slash (e.g. release/), you'll need to specify the origin repository in the branch names to make sure changes are picked up. So e.g. origin/release/
>
> Possible options:
>
> - **`<branchName>`**
>     Tracks/checks out the specified branch. If ambiguous the first result is taken, which is not necessarily the expected one. Better use
>     `refs/heads/<branchBame>`.
>     E.g. master, feature1`,...
> - **`refs/heads/<branchName>`**
>     Tracks/checks out the specified branch.
>     E.g. `refs/heads/master`, `refs/heads/featurel/master`, ...
>
> ...

What ambiguity can occur here and how prefixing with `refs/heads` helps with that?

Comment: I think the answer you're looking for is explained in the jenkins text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A branch name consisting only of letters a-f and numbers 0-9 could clash with a commit hash, leading to ambiguity.

You also might have a tag that has the same name as a branch.

Answer (score 2):

This is specifically a Jenkins issue, not a Git issue.  [1615903's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54711756/1256452) is for a closely-related Git issue.

The documentation you quoted spells out the reason:

> When not presented with a full path **the plugin will only use the part of the string right of the last slash. Meaning `foo/bar` will actually match `bar`.**